# Throwing an error in JavaScript without using new keyword

Tags: javascript

I have seen that code used in a tutorial:

```
Error().stack
```

I works just fine. An error is thrown and the call stack can be printed to the console.

But how is that possible?

I was rather sure that an error-object has to be created using the new-keyword: new Error()

If someone understands the usage without new, then I would appreciate his/her answer.

The complete code:

```
function funcA(){
   funcB();  
}

function funcB(){
   funcC();
}

function funcC(){
    console.log(Error().stack); //Error is only used to show the call stack
}

funcA();

/*console output
"Error
    at funcC (example.js:15:17) <-- funcC is at the top of the callstack because it was called last
    at funcB (example.js:12:5)
    at funcA (example.js:9:5)   <-- funcA is at the bottom of the call stack because it was called first
    at example.js:17:1"
*/
```

Comment: *The global Error object contains no methods of its own.* Not sure where you saw this

Comment: `stack` is a property, and a non-standard one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The only way to raise an error without creating a new object that I'm aware of, is throwing `throw "This is an error"`

Comment: As nico suggests there is no method on the Error object. Perhaps the code you were looking at modified the prototype (shudder)?

Comment: can you tell us more about the context? is there a framework used here? on which browser? It's non-standard, so it might be a functionality that belongs to a specific browser, or a framework that adds this to the Error prototype

Comment: Would like to see the code sample where you saw this. Might be a static method for a custom overriden Error object ? as @NicoVanBelle said, the error Object has no 'stack' method. It has a non-standard stack property though.

Comment: @Kaddath, No framework involved. Have added the complete example to my question.

Comment: I have tried it myself on Chrome and there it worked.

Comment: @mizech please be more careful: your question starts with `Error.stack()` but later on that changes to `Error().stack` which is something entirely different (and still non-standard btw).

Comment: That's the tutorial: https://www.edx.org/course/asynchronous-programming-javascript-microsoft-dev234x-1

Comment: @Indeed. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: yes, much different like this. Error() will return you an error object, so that you can access to the (non-standard) property `stack` in it

Comment: Who says you have to use the new keyword?   You don't need `new` for some things, like `Object()` or `Array()`...  `new` basically creates a new `this` for the function you're calling, if a function doesn't use `this` it may be possible to omit `new` without side effects.  But better to use `new` because it's better to be ignorant of the implementation of the functions you're calling.